# How to validate Zod Object depending on value of parent object

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, zod

I have a zod schema like this:

```
export const memberSchema = z
  .object({
    name: z.string().min(3),
    lastname: z.string().min(3),
    nationality: zCountries,
    birthdate: z.date(),
    email: z.string().email(),
    tutor: z
      .object({
        name: z.string(),
        lastname: z.string(),
        documentType: zDocumentationType,
        documentValue: z.string(),
        email: z.string().email(),
        phone: z.string().regex(/^\d{9}$/)
      })
  }).refine((data) => .....)
```

Is it possible to validate tutor object is required only if birthdate is under 18 ?
Because if member is +18 this fields are not needed.

I know how to validate a field depending of another one in refine function, but I don't know how to validate and entire object...

**EXAMPLE:**

- { birthdate: '20/02/2015'} -> ALL Fields in `tutor` has to be filled and passing zod tutor object validation
- {birthdate: '09/05/1988' } -> Tutor object is undefined and returns true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `superRefine` call to add issues to the overall object. For example:

```js
export const memberSchema = z
  .object({
    name: z.string().min(3),
    lastname: z.string().min(3),
    nationality: zCountries,
    birthdate: z.date(),
    email: z.string().email(),
    tutor: tutorSchema.optional(),
  })
  .superRefine((obj, ctx) => {
    const ageInYears = getAgeInYears(obj.birthdate);
    if (ageInYears < 18 && obj.tutor === undefined) {
      ctx.addIssue({
        code: "custom",
        message: "Members under the age of 18 must have a tutor",
      });
    }
  });

console.log(
  memberSchema.safeParse({
    name: "Test",
    lastname: "Testerson",
    nationality: "USA",
    birthdate: new Date("2010-1-1"), // Some date less than 18 years ago
    email: "test@example.com",
  })
); // Logs failure with custom message

console.log(
  memberSchema.safeParse({
    name: "Test",
    lastname: "Testerson",
    nationality: "USA",
    birthdate: new Date("2010-1-1"), // Some date less than 18 years ago
    email: "test@example.com",
    tutor: {
      name: "Tutor",
      lastname: "Some tutor",
      phone: undefined,
      email: undefined,
      documentType: undefined,
      documentValue: undefined,
    },
  })
); // Logs success
```

Note that going from the `Date` object to their age in years is potentially non-trivial, so I've left that as an exercise for the reader.

The main trick is to make the tutor field optional, and then to use the refine to say, "no actually it must be defined if the user is over 18".

#### A note on types

Unfortunately, this approach does not give you any firmer type guarantees once you know that the user is under 18. If you want the type system to track this for you, you could split the types along the `birthdate` and use `z.brand` to attach that additional information, but it may be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Thanks @Souperman but maybe my tutor object with z.unions is wrong, I include undefined because it can be undefined if member is +18, but if the member is under 18 all fields in tutor has to be REQUIRED and passing the object validation, not only one field filled. 
I Edit my question

Answer (score 0):

After many tries I got what I want with `z.union` between `object` and `undefined` and super refine.

Here is my code. Hope it helps someone in future.

```
export const memberSchema = z
  .object({
    name: z.string().min(3),
    lastname: z.string().min(3),
    nationality: zCountries,
    birthdate: z.date(),
    email: z.string().email(),
    tutor: z.union([
      z.object({
        name: zTutorString,
        lastname: zTutorString,
        document: zTutorString,
        email: zTutorString.email(),
        phone: zTutorString.regex(/^\d{9}$/)
      }),
      z.undefined()
    ])
  })
  .superRefine((data, ctx) => {
    const validation =
      data.birthdate.getFullYear() + 18 < new Date().getFullYear() ||
      (data.birthdate.getFullYear() + 18 > new Date().getFullYear() && data.tutor !== undefined)
    if (!validation) {
      tutorFields.forEach((field) => {
        if (!data.tutor || (data.tutor && !data.tutor[field as keyof typeof data.tutor])) {
          ctx.addIssue({
            code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
            message: i18n.t('validation.required_tutor'),
            path: ['tutor', field]
          })
        }
      })
    }
  })
```